# Fluid grid system with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html structure for a container which consists an unordered list of elements

```
  <div className="container">
    <ul className="list-group">
        <li className="list-group-item">
            <div className="items col-md-3"><p>Username: {this.props.username}</p></div>
            <div className="items col-md-3"><p>First Name: {this.props.firstName}</p></div>
            <div className="items col-md-3"><p>Last Name: {this.props.lastName}</p></div>
            <div className="items">
                <button className="btn btn-success btn-xs">{this.props.status}</button>
            </div>  
            <div className="items">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="items">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
            </div>
            <div className="items">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </div>

        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The layout looks ok initially but upon resizing the browser some of the elements start losing their fluidity. Could someone help me point out on how i can improve upon the above html structure? What built in classes from bootstrap should be applicable in this scenario?

I also had some additional styling added

```
  <style type="text/css">
     .items{
        display: inline-block;
     }
     button{
        width: 100px;
     }
     .glyphicon{
        padding-left: 30px;
     }
  </style>
```

**Edit:** Also i am making use of React hence "className" instead of "class"

Comment: You need to use the attribute 'class' and not 'className'. For starters.

Comment: Also, for fluid layout you should use container-fluid

Comment: @Hoshts className because of React

Comment: Then that makes sense I guess. You should provide such info because it looks very wrong for normal html/CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using Bootstrap's [container-fluid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) class.

Comment: thanks @A.Gent may i ask would the element positioning break upon resizing browser for div elements that dont have the class="col" defined on them, in the posted markup? I feel that why some of those child elements dont aglin properly upon resizing